# Android RecyclerView - StaggeredGridLayoutManager messes up width when scrolling

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have items with different height and I want the width always to match the parent.

When I set the RecyclerView it looks like this:

[image]

which is what I want, but when I start scrolling it messes up the width of the items below and looks like this:

[image]

This is the code:

```
val manager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
manager.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS

recyclerViewGallery.adapter = adapterMemes
recyclerViewGallery.layoutManager = manager
```

and XML of itemview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/galleyImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gallery" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The images are loaded from url so I tried to "reset" each item after they are loaded:

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(thumb)
    .into(holder.image)

holder.image.post {
    holder.image.requestLayout()
}
```

so what's wrong here? Android is such a broken mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what I've changed to make it work:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

on the ImageView